# Microsoft Graph Admin Consent Flow Doesn't Contain Refresh Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get refresh token also in the [admin consent flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant)?
I've received `access_token` but not `refresh_token` even though I've included the `offline_access` permission in the **delegated permissions**.

to be more clear: I need to get to the users drive files (i.e get/update files) of the entire tenant (organization). therefore  i'm requesting **Application Permissions** and [Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint). 
therefore I use the **client_credentials grant** in order to get the **entire tenant** access_token but **unfortunately with no refresh_token in order to extend time of privileges of the tenant for more then 1 hour.**

- if i misuse the protocols above clarification will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

While Marc's answer is correct, I think the whole thing can be explained in a little more detail:

To get full access to a tenant (i.e. not just resources associated with the current consenting user), then you need to use the Admin Consent flow. However, unlike other flows in Graph's OAuth, you do not require a `refresh_token` to maintain access. Instead, you can simply request an `access_token` at any time once an admin has consented. Each `access_token` lasts 60 minutes.

Having first used other flows such as the Management API and Graph's Code Grant flow, this one confused me, but it's actually even simpler than those.

To get consent, simply direct the admin to the following URL:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Their Tenant ID]/adminconsent?client_id=[Your Client ID]&redirect_uri=[Your Redirect URI]`

Your redirect URI will get a response with params:

`?admin_consent=True&tenant=[Their Tenant ID]`

Once you've received this confirmation, you can request an `access_token` at any time by sending a POST request with the following form fields:

```
client_id: [Your Client ID],
client_secret: [Your Client Secret],
scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
grant_type: 'client_credentials'
```

To the following URI:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Their Tenant ID]/oauth2/v2.0/token`

The response will contain a new 60 minute `access_token` and you can simply call it again whenever required.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh Tokens are only returned when both `offline_access` is requested and you are using the Authorization Code Grant.

More importantly, if you *are* receiving an `access_token` then you are *not* executing the Admin Consent workflow. Administrative Consent is only used for consenting to your application's scopes. The [Admin Consent response](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) does not contain an `access_token`, it only contains the Tenant ID (for the tenant that was consented) and a boolean that tells you if consent was granted as query parameters:

```
 http://{return_uri}/?tenant=[tenant id]&admin_consent=[True/False]
```

If you are receiving an `access_token` then you are using either the Authorization Code, Client Credentials, or Implicit grants.

UPDATE:

There is no refresh token issued for Client Credentials, you simply request a new token from the `/token` endpoint as needed.

Comment: you totally right. but after i received the tenant_id after the admin approved my app in the admin consent - what is the way to receive long time token (more then 1 hour) that will be used to do operations on all of the admin organization?

Comment: The default will always be 1hr. You need to use Auth Code in order to obtain a refresh token.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I've edited the question to clarify my issue. can you check that out?